# Equally space elements using display: flex;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am experimenting with Flexbox for some UI work I'm doing at the moment. I have a group of select boxes that i have styled with some basic css. My question to you is how can i equally space the devices without one or two looking too close to one another?

```css
#device-select {
    background: #2d2d2d;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
}
.rad, .ckb {
    cursor:pointer;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.rad > input, .ckb > input {
    /* Hide original radio and checkboxes */
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.rad > i {
    font-size: 64px;
    color: #fff;
}
.rad:hover > i {
    /* HOVER <i> STYLE */
    color: wheat;
}
.rad > input:checked + i {
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="device-select">
    <label class="rad">
        <input type="radio" name="device-choice" value="desktop" /> <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
Desktop</label>
    <label class="rad">
        <input type="radio" name="device-choice" value="tablet" /> <i class="fa fa-tablet"></i>
Tablet</label>
    <label class="rad">
        <input type="radio" name="device-choice" value="mobile" /> <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
Mobile</label>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your css for `fa`?

Comment: it's external stylesheet - Font Awesome

Comment: its font awesome's css @SaagarEliasJacky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `flex: 1;` from `.rad, .ckb`

New code should be

```
.rad, .ckb {
    cursor:pointer;    
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thought you needed flex: 1; for ie10 support though?

Comment: Add `-ms-flexbox` for IE10 support. Check [this.](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)

Comment: Try to add this @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 
.rad, .ckb {
flex:1;
} 
}

Comment: No need to do a media query for it

Comment: You can give separate stylesheet for IE10 as well

Comment: You can't, you can't do conditional tagging in IE

Comment: Have you try justify-content CSS property?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `flex:1;` from `.rad, .ckb` class does the magic.
Check [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mask2486/x9u70hue/).

Also read [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to know more about flex properties.

Answer (score -1):

Can you have DIVs inside `#device-select` and then inside these DIVs you will have LABELs? So you can apply margin or padding to LABEL tag. Of course this is only if you want another DIVs as LABELs wrapper.